# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libnetcdf.13.dylib ...Reason: image not found : GMT on MacOS Big Sur

Tags: macos, github, netcdf, macos-big-sur

I installed GMT4 from the source code on my Mac machine. Now, when I try using any command (e.g. pscoast) from GMT, It results into following error:
"dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libnetcdf.13.dylib
Referenced from: **********/GMT4.5.16/bin/pscoast
Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6"

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested [here](https://github.com/NCAR/pynio/issues/4), the problem might be due to the fact that GMT expects `libnetcdf` to be built with different options than it is actually built on your machine. I had a similar problem when downloading ncview. My `libnetcdf` was built with `conda-forge` so installing ncview with `conda-forge`helped.

If you're using conda as well, you can type `conda list` in a shell to see what was used to build the packages, and then maybe `conda remove` GMT to install it